How Are Orlicz Spaces Used in Practice?
I have studied some basic properties of Orlicz spaces from this note: https://leonard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/papers/Leonard-Orlicz%20spaces.pdf. However, I am struggling to understand the practical applications of Orlicz spaces.
Firstly, I came across a paper: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-06/S0002-9939-09-09805-0/S0002-9939-09-09805-0.pdf, which extends the $L^p$ estimates for the Poisson equation and has connections to Orlicz spaces. Could someone explain how Orlicz spaces are used in the context of PDEs, particularly in relation to this paper?
Secondly, the note mentions that Orlicz spaces corresponding to the Young functions $\theta(s) = \exp(|s|) - 1$ and $\theta(s) = \exp(|s|) - 1 - |s|$ are associated with the study of relative entropy. Could anyone provide a detailed example or further explanation of this association?
Thank you in advance for your help!
